# Laravel Dusk use test structure in service can't connect

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-dusk

This is a weird one. So I have the code below that I have transplanted into a service in order to run it from a controller and to be able to pass in some information.

```
$this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
    $browser->visit('https://urlforsite.co.uk/find-an-engineer/')
        ->type("EngineerId", "2231321")
        ->click('#checkEngineer');

    if ($browser->assertSee("Engineer cannot be found")) {
        dd("hello");
    }

    $text = $browser->text('.engineer-search-results-container .search-result .col-md-8 .row .col-xs-10 h3');
        dd($text);
    });
```

Expected outcome would be one of the DD's

`dd("hello);` or `dd($text);`

Actual outcome:

```
Failed to connect to localhost port 9515: Connection refused
```

If I run it in an actual `dusk` test and run `php artisan dusk` it works correctly. Is there something that command runs first so it can get to the outside? Can this even be done?

Comment: check if something is already running on the same port and your executable has required permissions.

Comment: Don't have anything else running on that port on this machine. It is an external site so not sure why it won't connect

Comment: Is your chromedriver or whatever driver you are using having executable permissions?

Comment: i am not sure what that is

Comment: It does run fine if I run `php artisan dusk` so it's not a bug as such just where I am trying to take advantage of it isn't working

Comment: you need to initiate the driver then, please see https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/356

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by [Arun Code](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4945102/arun-code) in the link: https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/356 there is response that allows you to open a browser from a service/controller like so:

```
use Facebook\WebDriver\Chrome\ChromeOptions;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;
use Laravel\Dusk\Browser;
use Laravel\Dusk\Chrome\ChromeProcess;

$process = (new ChromeProcess)->toProcess();
$process->start();
$options = (new ChromeOptions)->addArguments(['--disable-gpu', '--headless']);
$capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::chrome()->setCapability(ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options);
$driver = retry(5, function () use($capabilities) {
    return RemoteWebDriver::create('http://localhost:9515', $capabilities);
}, 50);
$browser = new Browser($driver);
$browser->visit('https://www.google.com');
$browser->quit();
$process->stop();
```